# updatepanel only updates first time then wont update again

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

I am using a GridView within an updatepanel.
I have gridview generated edit and cancel buttons.

The first time I click edit, the gridview edit template displays fine.  Then if I click cancel, or edit on another row, nothing happens.  It seems that the update panel has ceased to work.

If I do the same thing without the update panel the postback works fine and the gridview does what it should (although it's quite cumbersome as it refreshes the whole page, which is why I want to use the updatepanel!)

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSentOrders" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="gvSentOrders" runat="server"
                        autogeneratecolumns="False"
                        allowpaging="false" 
                        DataKeyNames="titxn_id" 
                        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="gvAlternate"                  
                        CssClass="gvTable" 
                        OnRowDataBound="addSentTotals" 
                        OnRowEditing="editOrder" 
                        OnRowCancelingEdit="cancelEdit"     
                        OnDataBound="showSentTotals"                    
                        AutoGenerateEditButton="true" 
                        AutoGenerateDeleteButton="false" 
                        ShowFooter="true" 
                        ShowHeader="true">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <table class="basketHeader">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="basketTitle"><asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text="Order Date" /></td>
                                    <td class="basketPX"><asp:Label ID="lblPXOffer" runat="server" Text="Part Ex" /></td>
                                    <td class="basketCash"><asp:Label ID="lblCashOffer" runat="server" Text="Cash" /></td>
                                    <td class="basketDelete">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>                                
                            </table>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table class="basket">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="basketTitle"><asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("{0:dd MMMM yyyy}", Eval("titxn_date")) %>' /></td>
                                    <td class="basketPX"><asp:Label ID="lblPXOfferItem" runat="server" Text='<%# "£" + Eval("titxn_totalpxatsend") %>' /></td>
                                    <td class="basketCash"><asp:Label ID="lblCashOfferItem" runat="server" Text='<%# "£" + Eval("titxn_totalcashatsend") %>' /></td>
                                    <td class="basketDelete"><asp:Button ID="btnEdit" Text="" CommandArgument="1" runat="server" CssClass="editButton" ToolTip="View Order" OnClick="viewOrder" /></td>
                                </tr>                                
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <table class="basket">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="basketTitle"><asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("{0:dd MMMM yyyy}", Eval("titxn_date")) %>' /></td>
                                    <td class="basketPX"><asp:Label ID="lblPXOfferItem" runat="server" Text='<%# "£" + Eval("titxn_totalpxatsend") %>' /></td>
                                    <td class="basketCash"><asp:Label ID="lblCashOfferItem" runat="server" Text='<%# "£" + Eval("titxn_totalcashatsend") %>' /></td>
                                    <td class="basketDelete"><asp:Button ID="btnStopEdit" Text="" CommandArgument="-1" runat="server" CssClass="stopEditButton" ToolTip="View Order" OnClick="viewOrder" /></td>
                                </tr>                                
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="4">
                                        Items GridView here...
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="4">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("titxn_name") + ", " + Eval("titxn_addressnumber") + " " + Eval("titxn_addressone") + ", " + Eval("titxn_addresstown") + ", " + Eval("titxn_addresscounty") + ", " + Eval("titxn_addresscountry") + ", " + Eval("titxn_addresspostcode") + "." %>' />   
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>                        
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <table class="basketTotals">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="basketTitle">Total Still To Arrive</td>
                                    <td class="basketPX"><asp:Label ID="lblPxTotal" runat="server" Text="" /></td>
                                    <td class="basketCash"><asp:Label ID="lblCashTotal" runat="server" Text="" /></td>
                                    <td class="basketDelete">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>                                
                            </table>                  
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <p>There is no orders still being processed.  Look like we've already completed all the orders you've sent us!</p>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
            </asp:GridView>    
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind....

```
protected void editOrder(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    gvSentOrders.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    bindSentGridView();
}

protected void cancelEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    gvSentOrders.EditIndex = -1;
    bindSentGridView();
}
```

Any thoughts would be a great help.
Thanks.

Comment: It might be silently failing. Did you debug to check if the second time reach the code behind and what's happening there?

Comment: It seems to step through everything absolutely fine, just doesn't does the update at the end.  It all works fine with a full postback if the update panel is taken out too.

Comment: Are you getting any Javascript errors?

Comment: Ah.  You could be onto something there....I get this one after the first update:  "Uncaught ReferenceError: resetjQuery is not defined"

Comment: Solved! Thank you.  Had a rogue JS call in the master page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was a JS error from another bit of code that stopped the AJAX updating the panel.

Comment: The help and debug messages for the Updatepanel are still close to (if not entirely) non-existing. Thanks for pointing me into the right direction with this.

Answer (score 2):

Since the UpdatePanel has a property UpdateMode="Conditional", you need to update it from the codebehind on every postback:

```
protected void editOrder(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    gvSentOrders.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    bindSentGridView();
    upSentOrders.Update();
}

protected void cancelEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    gvSentOrders.EditIndex = -1;
    bindSentGridView();
    upSentOrders.Update();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Aleafonso.  I've tried that too and it doesn't make any difference.  It steps through the upSentOrders.Update(), but does not actual refresh on screen.  Unless it does and the gridview editindex hasn't changed for some reason...although I can't see why that would happen either!

Comment: Ok. Difficult to find out the reason, then. I'm just guessing: if this UpdatePanel is contained in other UpdatePanel, you will need to Update both of them in the codebehind. Otherwise, I'm afraid I can't think of anything else

Answer (score 0):

Just to make a test:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSentOrders" runat="server"
                 UpdateMode="Conditional"
                 ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
```

Make sure to set GridView's property `EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks = false;`

Comment: Thanks Leniel.  I've tried playing with those settings and doesn't change things.  Still wont update after the first one!

Comment: So, check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/533277/114029 I think it has to do with the way you're setting your DataSource. Check this sample by Microsoft too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bb386452.aspx

Comment: Not sure that helps.  It is doing the first update fine, so I know it is working as it should, it's subsequent updates that do not render on screen, even though it steps through the update command in the code behind.